# re-ordering legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to re-order my legend in ggplot such that "control" is listed first and than concentration is arranged low-high. I have both put my dataset in the order I would like the legend and tried scale_fill_discrete.

Can you spot any reason this is not working?

```
p <- ggplot(data = deviation_cloth, aes(x = day, y = Deviation))+
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(Labels)), size = 1)+
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("control", "1E-3","0.01", "0.1", "1", "10"))

p + labs(color = "Conc", x = "Day", y = "Result ")
```

[image]

Comment: fill != color....?

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question without leaving a comment: That's the wrong way, learning to improve questions requires feed-back. Please help us all to learn...

Comment: Try `deviation_cloth$Labels <- factor(deviation_cloth$Labels, level = c("control", "1E-3","0.01", "0.1", "1", "10"))`

Comment: Perhaps I was too cryptic. You mapped the `color` aesthetic but attempted to adjust the legend using `scale_fill_discrete` not `scale_color_discrete`.

Comment: @JMiller Please always add a small example data set as R code to your question that is used by your code so that we can reproduce the problem and propose answers (even though many users are clever enough to recognize the problem just by reading ;-) THX!

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple things: comments previously mentioned this, but you mapped Labels to color, but then use a scale function for fill instead. Since it's a line, color makes sense; just change to `scale_color_discrete`.

Second thing is that you want the limits argument, not the breaks one. Setting limits allows you to define what categories are included and what order they appear in. You can change to `scale_color_discrete(limits = c("control", "1E-3","0.01", "0.1", "1", "10"))`

Alternatively, you could use an ordered factor and arrange the levels for that variable as you want. `fct_relevel` from the `forcats` package, part of the tidyverse, makes it easy to do this without having to give all the levels manually.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this ...

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  data_frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    y = c(2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6),
    z = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z)) +
  geom_line()

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z)) +
  geom_line() +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(reverse = T))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just changing the Legend only

Today, it looks like we can also change the Legend order alone by adding a
`limits=`
declaration to our `scale_*_*()`.

For example,
having set my chosen colors per factor with

```
scale_fill_manual(
                  values= c(
                        "factor1" = "#64af38", 
                        "factor2" = "#0051e8", 
                        "factor3" = "#cc6389"
                        )
                 )
```

I can force the legend order to something different,
say factor3 then factor1 then factor2
by simply updating this to

```
scale_fill_manual(
                  values= c(
                        "factor1" = "#64af38", 
                        "factor2" = "#0051e8", 
                        "factor3" = "#cc6389"
                        ),
                   limits= c(
                        "factor3", 
                        "factor1", 
                        "factor2"
                        )
                  )
```